# Resizing Header Image to Fit Screen Size

Tags: css, image, web, image-resizing

I am trying to get the header image of my new website (using WordPress) to resize automatically dependent on what type of device I am viewing from.  I have tried to implement additional CSS from other people's suggestions but nothing seems to work for me. When viewing on a desktop, I am happy with how it looks but viewing from a phone does not look good.

Please help! My website is:

maximizingchange.com

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the specific section of the code which is causing the problem to your question (not as a link). https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, you are using background-image for your header. Try adding the below lines in your additional CSS section to fix it.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) { 
    #masthead.header-image{
      padding: 30px 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: initial;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use:

```
width: 100vw;
height: auto;
```

This will make your image with 100% of the width of users device.

Comment: Hello SamL.  Probably a stupid question but would I just add those two lines in the "Additional CSS"?  If so, I do not believe that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then adding a class in `<img>` will make the image responsive. `class = "img-responsive"` . You can add a class over this and set your max-width.

Comment: Hello Chandru. I am using WordPress.  Would this be a similar fix?

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, yes.